# Android Certifications Recognized

Tags: android

I am working as an Android developer for already more than 1 year and I was wondering, if there exists any Android certifications well-known as those from Oracle,Microsoft or Cisco ?

Answer (score 5):

Google just released the  **Associate Android Developer Certification**
on the event I/O 2016 released. There are some links below where you can get more info about it.

**Certification specs**
https://www.udacity.com/google-certifications

**Announcement on Google I/O 2016** 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yu2oGere_Mc&index=13&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc8jQTUYvIfqA9lMvSGQWtte

On the other hand, I've created a repo where I'm sharing everything I'm learning about the certification https://github.com/Amejia481/Associate-Android-Developer-Certification

Answer (score 0):

If he can code and make apps that is the best certification and there is no substitute for it, as for as I know there are no such certification. Remember Oracle, Microsoft and Cisco have nothing to do with android (Oracle only does java).

Comment: I asked if there are similar certifications, not relating to them

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's too late but Google announced Android certification exam on 18th july I guess. I am preparing for it but I  am unable to find any discussion,forum or any kind of reviews for it. So I am unable to judge what the content of their exam will be which leads me to think twice before appearing for this certification exam.